# How do I enable and use the password module for Drupal 6?

Tags: 7

I've uploaded the module to my site, but it doesn't appear in the list of modules so I can't enable it. Does this module work differently than other modules?

https://drupal.org/project/password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this module works as any other module. See my screenshot as I can see it in my module listing - [image: module listing]

Are you sure you have it in sites/all/modules/ ? Are the permissions correctly set?

Comment: Yes, it's in the correct location and I'm logged in as the site administrator so permissions shouldn't be an issue.  I've uploaded other modules to the same folder and can see them in the admin list.  Maybe a conflict with other modules?

Comment: No, drupal.org should not allow name conflicts

Comment: Also, I can't see your screenshot - dropbox is forbidden by our network here.

Comment: I updated the screenshot

Comment: Ahh... I see it now.  Thanks.  Silly me, I was expecting it to actually be named Password.